# Java JDBC Template Equivalent for EntityFramework Include, map join list into subclass

Tags: java, c#, .net, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Does Java JDBC Template have the equivalent of Entity Framework Linq Include? Whats the best way to conduct this if not in the JDBCTemplate library?

For example in .Net, the following example would map a single-to-many database relationship into Product Class, with Suppliers and Locations below automatically.

**SQL**

```
select * from dbo.Product
inner join dbo.Suppliers 
   on suppliers.productId = product.productId
inner join dbo.Locations 
   on locations.productId = product.productId
```

**Target Class:**

```
public class Product{
    private Long productId;
    private String productName;
    private List<Supplier> suppliers; 
    private List<Location> locations;   
}
```

**C#**

```
List<Product> productList = dbContext.Product.Include(x=>x.Supplier)
              .Include(x=>x.Location);
```

**Java JDBC Template Proposed Solution:**

How can this be done with Java and JDBC Template? Is there a clean way? I am thinking of converting the sql query into JSON for suppliers and locations, and mapping.

```
String productQuery = 
  SELECT pr.productId
      ,pr.productName
        ,(select *
          from dbo.Supplier supp
        where supp.supplierId = pr.supplierId
      for json auto) as SuppliersJson
        ,(select *
          from dbo.Location loc
        where loc.locationId = pr.locationId
      for json auto) as LocationsJson
  FROM dbo.Product pr;
```

With this,

```
List<Product> products = namedJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(productQuery, new ProductMapper());

@Override
public ProductMapper mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setProductId(rs.getLong("ProductId"));
    product.setProductName(rs.getString("ProductName"));
    product.setSuppliers(new ObjectMapper().readValue(suppliersJson, Supplier.class));
    product.setLocations(new ObjectMapper().readValue(locationsJson, Location.class));
    return product;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java offers you different options to implement the desired behavior.

First, as a naive solution, you could try using JDBC directly and iterate over the different results returned by your query, taking into consideration the last fetched result of every type, and build the corresponding object graph on your own.

For instance, given the following query (note that it is ordered):

```sql
select pr.*, sp.*, loc.* from dbo.Product pr
inner join dbo.Suppliers 
   on suppliers.productId = product.productId
inner join dbo.Locations 
   on locations.productId = product.productId
order by pr.productId, sp.supplierId, loc.locationId
```

You can use something like the following to iterate and build your object graph:

```java
// You can use PreparedStatement as well if you prefer to
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
Long lastProductId = null;
Product product = null;
Long lastSupplierId = null;
Supplier supplier = null;
Long lastLocationId = null;
Location location = null;
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while (rs.next()) {
     Long productId = rs.getLong("ProductId");
     if (lastProductId == null || productId != lastProductId) {
       product = new Product();
       products.add(product);

       product.setProductId(productId);
       product.setProductName(rs.getString("ProductName"));
       product.setSuppliers(new ArrayList<>());
       product.setLocations(new ArrayList<>());

       lastProductId = productId;
       lastSupplierId = null;
       lastLocationId = null;
     }

     // Suppliers
     Long supplierId = rs.getLong("SupplierId");
     if (lastSupplierId == null || supplierId != lastSupplierId) {
       supplier = new Supplier();
       product.getSuppliers().add(supplier);

       supplier.setSupplierId(supplierId);
       //...

       lastSupplierId = supplierId;
     }

     // Locations
     Long locationId = rs.getLong("LocationId");
     if (lastLocationId == null || locationId != lastLocationId) {
       location = new Location();
       product.getLocations().add(location);

       location.setLocationId(locationId);
       //...

       lastLocationId = locationId;
     }


  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With `JdbcTemplate` probably the way to go would be using [`queryForList`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). Consider for instance:

```java
// Every Map in the list is composed by the column names as keys and 
// the corresponding values as values
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(productQuery);

// The same code as above, but taking the information from the result Maps
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
Long lastProductId = null;
Product product = null;
Long lastSupplierId = null;
Supplier supplier = null;
Long lastLocationId = null;
Location location = null;
for (Map row : rows) {
  Long productId = (Long)row.get("ProductId");
  if (lastProductId == null || productId != lastProductId) {
     product = new Product();
     products.add(product);

     product.setProductId(productId);
     product.setProductName((String)row.get("ProductName"));
     product.setSuppliers(new ArrayList<>());
     product.setLocations(new ArrayList<>());

     lastProductId = productId;
     lastSupplierId = null;
     lastLocationId = null;
   }

   // Suppliers
   Long supplierId = (Long)row.get("supplierId");
   if (lastSupplierId == null || supplierId != lastSupplierId) {
     supplier = new Supplier();
     product.getSuppliers().add(supplier);

     supplier.setSupplierId(supplierId);
     //...

     lastSupplierId = supplierId;
   }

   // Locations
   Long locationId = (Long)row.get("locationId");
   if (lastLocationId == null || locationId != lastLocationId) {
     location = new Location();
     product.getLocations().add(location);

     location.setLocationId(locationId);
     //...

     lastLocationId = locationId;
   }
}
```

As you can see, both approaches are neither very extensible nor maintainable, although suitable.

Similarly to EntityFramework, Java provides different ORM that you can use to alleviate these problems.

The first one is [MyBatis](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html).

Simplifying a lot, with MyBatis you need a `SqlSession`, an artifact that correctly configured will allow you to obtain a reference to a `Mapper`.

A `Mapper` is just an interface that declares different methods, one per every operation you need to perform against the database. A typical code block will be by like the following:

```java
try (SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
  ProductMapper mapper = session.getMapper(ProductMapper.class);
  //...
}
```

Where:

```java
public interface ProductMapper {
  List<Product> getProducts();
}
```

For every `Mapper` you need to provide an associated [XML configuration file](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html). This file will define as namespace the `Mapper` and, typically, for every method defined in the `Mapper`, the appropriate configuration. For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace=“my.pkg.ProducMapper”>

  <resultMap id=“productWithSuppliersAndLocationsResultMap" type=“my.pkg.Product”>
    <id property=“productId”         column=“ProductId” />
    <result property=“productName”   column=“ProductName” />
    <collection property=“suppliers” ofType=“my.pkg.Supplier”>
      <id property=“supplierId"      column=“SupplierId” />
      <!— ... —/>
    </collection>
    <collection property=“locations” ofType=“my.pkg.Location”>
      <id property=“locationId"     column=“LocationId” />
      <!— ... —/>
    </collection>
  </resultMap>

  <select id=“getProducts” resultMap="productWithSuppliersAndLocationsResultMap">
   select pr.*, sp.*, loc.* from dbo.Product pr
                 inner join dbo.Suppliers 
                     on suppliers.productId = product.productId
                 inner join dbo.Locations 
                     on locations.productId = product.productId
       order by pr.productId, sp.supplierId, loc.locationId
  </select>

</mapper>
```

As you can guess, it will use Reflection to populate the different properties from the provided SQL statement according to the provided `resultMap`.

It can be easily [integrated with Spring](http://mybatis.org/spring/) as well.

One more option, as explained as well by @utrucceh in his/her answer, is the use of [JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html), which is the Java *de jure* ORM standard.

To deal with it, you first need to transform your plain objects in [entities](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html), defining their columns and the relations within them. For example:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;

    @Column(name = “ProductName”, nullable = false)
    private String productName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<Supplier> suppliers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<Location> locations;
    
    //…

}

@Entity
@Table(name=“Suppliers”)
public class Supplier {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long supplierId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name=“productId”, nullable = false)
  private Product product;

  //…

}

@Entity
@Table(name=“Locations”)
public class Location {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long locationId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name=“productId”, nullable = false)
  private Product product;

  //…

}
```

This object graph can be queried in different ways.

For instance, you can use the [Criteria API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html).

The code could be something similar to the following:

```java
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Product> query = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
Root<Product> root = query.from(Product.class);
query.select(root);
// Using fetchJoin will instruct the ORM to fetch, equivalent in a certain
// way to Include(), your results. The JPA implementation will do it best to
// optimize the way to return the actual information
Join<Product, Supplier> joinSuppliers = root.fetchJoin("suppliers", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Product, Location> joinLocations = root.fetchJoin("locations", JoinType.INNER);
List<Product> results = query.getResultList();
```

As an alternative, you could provide your SQL query as well, for example:

```java
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery(
  "SELECT DISTINCT pr FROM Product pr
          INNER JOIN FETCH pr.suppliers s
          INNER JOIN FETCH pr.locations l
  ");
List<Product> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Sorry for the brevity of the examples, but both JPA and MyBatis are very extensive subjects.

JPA implementations like [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/) can be easily integrated with Spring.

The [Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa) project provides great value added as well.

I realize that in my answer I actually didn't answer your question, I just provided different alternatives to achieve the desired results.

The actual answer is no, AFAIK `JdbcTemplate` doesn't include any functionally similar to the one provided by `Include`.

In Entity Framework `Include` identify the set of related entities you want to be fetched with the parent result.

In Java, the more similar approach to `Include` will be using JPA, with their entities and relationships as suggested, and the use of `fetchJoin` or a `FETCH JOIN` clause in your SQL query like indicated: that will actually fetch the related entities you need to.

Comment: thanks, this is great, however it seems my answer is more simple, has less lines of code, are there benefits to doing the first method you proposed? thanks

Comment: Hi @mattsmith5. Thank you very much for the feedback. No mate, I edited my answer trying explaining it better. No, `JdbcTemplate` doesn't offer any similar to `Include`: in my examples I tried giving you advice of how to get the results using it, but be aware that as I told you need to actually fetch the results. The more suitable approach would be using an ORm, especially JPA, although MyBatis could be an option if you are starting using an ORM with Java, because its learning curve is lower, although JPA will offer you more powerful constructs and artifacts than MyBatis.

Comment: Sorry, because I realized your actual question. Yes, in my opinion mixing both a database and json conversion approach is not convenient. Please, rely on the database ORMs this kind of operations, they should perform them in a very efficient way and the solution is less error prone. In addition, think about database context, what is being or not managed by the database context itself: only if the operation is performed by the ORM you can obtain that level of coherence: the objects read by json with by out of the persistence context, I hope you get the idea.

Comment: hi, so your answer still stands? ok, thanks

Comment: Yes @mattsmith5. I am only sorry for don't give you an in depth explanation of the different concepts involved in some of the things mentioned in the answer, as I tried to explain, especially JPA is a very extensive topic. Having said that, please, do not hesitate to ask me if you need some additional information about any of the points mentioned in the answer.

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful, just sent points

Comment: You are welcome @mattsmith5. I am glad to hear that the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write like that. If you use Entity framework like **eclipseLink** or **hibernate** they are automatically mapping.
For example with your types:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
@XmlRootElement
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long productId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String productName;
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "productId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Supplier> suppliers;
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "productId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Location> locations;
    
    //set get

    
}
```

You can write your query simply like this:

```
List<Product> lst = em.createQuery("select a from Product a",Product.class).getResultList();
System.out.println(lst.getSuppliers().size());
```

Entity framework will automaticly fill those values but in any way I dont recommend this auto fetches for big systems for performance and ram usage.